# queryover and (x like 'a' or y like 'a')

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Hi
Is there any elegant way of combining 'like' and 'or' when i'm using queryover API?
for 'like' there is something like:

```
 query.WhereRestrictionOn(x=>x.Code).IsLike(codePart)
```

for 'or' i can do something like:

```
query.Where( x=>x.Code == codePart || x.Description== codePart)
```

but how can I create a query like this:

> select * from n where code like
>   '%abc%' or description like '%abc%'

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
query.Where(Restrictions.On<Type>(x => x.Code).IsLike(codePart) ||
            Restrictions.On<Type>(x => x.Description).IsLike(codePart))
```

Answer (score 60):

You could use the NHibernate **Disjunction** class to do this in a more elegant (IMHO) fashion:

```
var disjunction= new Disjunction();

disjunction.Add(Restrictions.On<Type>(e => e.Code).IsLike(codePart));
disjunction.Add(Restrictions.On<Type>(e => e.Description).IsLike(codePart));
//(and so on)
```

and then:

```
query.Where(disjunction)
```

Each "OR" is a separate instruction, which helps if you want to add the predicates conditionally.

Answer (score 9):

Another version of this, which depending on taste, you may like, is as follows:

```
query.Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()
         .Add(Restrictions.On<Type>(e => e.Code).IsLike(codePart))
         .Add(Restrictions.On<Type>(e => e.Description).IsLike(codePart)));
```