# Where ... In ... Or Where ... In ... with NHibernate IQueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I'm trying to emulate subject query with NHibernate's `IQueryOver`. So far I have

```
var q = CurrentSession.QueryOver<ObjectModel.Order>().
    WhereRestrictionOn(o => o.Buyer.ID).IsIn(partyIDs).
    WhereRestrictionOn(o => o.Seller.ID).IsIn(partyIDs);
```

This, however, generates an `and` query, whereas I need to have an `or` operator between two `where` clauses.

How is this done with `IQueryOver`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it usually is, found question soon after explaining the problem to general public. Thanks, guys!

```
var q = CurrentSession.QueryOver<ObjectModel.Order>();

q.RootCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Or(
    Restrictions.On<ObjectModel.Order>(o => o.Buyer.ID).IsIn(partyIDs),
    Restrictions.On<ObjectModel.Order>(o => o.Seller.ID).IsIn(partyIDs)));
```

Comment: you can check this too Anton [queryover and (x like 'a' or y like 'a')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541546/queryover-and-x-like-a-or-y-like-a)

Comment: @Burn Well worth a separate answer. Thanks!