# NHibernate how to write a query with like any item in a list or array

Tags: c#, nhibernate, oracle11g

I am struggling with the following. Can anyone help how to do this?

How to write nhibernate query to the following

```
select * from tableA where description like (*Any of the items from a lst*)

List<string> lst = new List<string>
{
     "AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD"
}
```

At the moment i am selecting all the records and applying this filtering on the in memory collection.

The actual code:

```
    private List<string> lst = new List<string>{
        "AMV",
        "BMVi",
        "CMV",
        "DTL"
    }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Asset> ReplayAssets(DateTime updatedDateTimeFrom, DateTime updatedDateTimeTo)
    {
        Asset assetAlias = null;
        var query = Session.QueryOver(() => assetAlias);

        //Here i need to add something like
        query.where(()=>assetAlias.title.like(*any item in the above list lst* )

        query.Where(() => assetAlias.LastUpdatedDate.IsBetween(updatedDateTimeFrom).And(updatedDateTimeTo));

        return query.Future<Asset>();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Use [QueryOver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541546/queryover-and-x-like-a-or-y-like-a)

Comment: Please add a bigger part of your code?

Comment: @GiladGreen i have updated with bigger part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple.

```
var lst = new List<string>
{
  "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"
};

var items = Session.Query<TableA>
  .Where(x => lst.Contains(x.Description))
  .ToList();
```